# Error: Compile Error: Comparison arguments must be compatible types: String, List<String> at line 30 column 20

Tags: apex, trigger, developer-console, sales

I'm getting an error on he below code please correct me. Not sure what's missing.

> ERROR : Error: Compile Error: Comparison arguments must be compatible types: String, List at line 30 column 20

Error showing at this line :

```
If(brick.ZTS_EU_Market__c == marketlst){
```

The more complete code is:

```
     public class ZIP_TerritoryBrickCodePopulation{   
         public void territoryBrickCodePopulation(List<Account> accList){
        
        String marketValue = system.label.BrickToTerritory_Market;
        List<String> marketlst = marketValue.split(',');
        Set<String> zipcodes=new Set<String>(); 
        Set<String> marketSet = new Set<String>();
        Set<String> zipMarketKey =new Set<String>();
          
        List<ZTS_GL_BrickToTerr__c> lstBrick = [select Id,Name,ZTS_EU_Market__c,ZTS_EU_BrickName__c,ZTS_EU_Territory__c from ZTS_GL_BrickToTerr__c];
         
        for(Account acc:accList){        
            
            for(ZTS_GL_BrickToTerr__c brick : lstBrick){
            
                If(brick.ZTS_EU_Market__c == marketlst){
                              
                    if(!String.isBlank(acc.ZTS_EU_Zip_Postal_Code__c) && acc.ZTS_EU_Market__c != ZTS_EU_GlobalConstants.MARKET_VAL && acc.ZTS_EU_Market__c != ZTS_EU_GlobalConstants.UK_MARKET_VAL){
                        zipcodes.add(acc.ZTS_EU_Zip_Postal_Code__c);
                    }else if(acc.ZTS_EU_Market__c == ZTS_EU_GlobalConstants.MARKET_VAL){
                        zipcodes.add(acc.ZTS_EU_State_County_Value__c);
                    }else if(!String.isBlank(acc.ZTS_EU_Zip_Postal_Code__c) && acc.ZTS_EU_Market__c == ZTS_EU_GlobalConstants.UK_MARKET_VAL){
                        zipcodes.add(acc.ZTS_EU_UK_PC4_from_Postalcode__c);
                    }
                    marketSet.add(acc.ZTS_EU_Market__c);
           }
         }
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply using an IDE would help you find such issues. Salesforce even has a free plugin for VSCode, plus all the [instructions](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quick-start-lightning-web-components/set-up-visual-studio-code) you need to install and get started with it.

The problem is that you are using a comparison between a string and a list:

```
If(brick.ZTS_EU_Market__c == marketlst){
```

should probably be:

```
If(marketlst.contains(brick.ZTS_EU_Market__c)){
```

This will then return true if the marketlst contains the specified EU Market value. Note that this is case and whitespace sensitive; this will be an exact match only.

Comment: Phil I have modified the code but getting this error. Pls help me I have updated error details.Thanks

Comment: Follow the path of setting up an IDE. Your whole development experience will be much smoother.

Comment: Sure Phil. For now can you help me to resolve the issue. till I'm getting another error and I have updated in post please check and help me accordingly. Thanks

Comment: By editing the question in the way you did, you invalidated the analysis part of my answer. Since I had provided an answer you should have simply raised a new question instead of updating this one; this Q&A posting is now confusing.